# How to get selector string with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Let say I have JSON like this:

```json
{
  "foobar": "data foobar",
  "foo": "data foo",
  "bar": "data bar",
  "baz": "data baz",
  "qux": "data qux",
  "quux": "data quux",
  "corge": "data corge",
  "grault": "data grault",
  "garply": "data garply",
  "waldo": "data waldo",
  "fred": "data fred",
  "plugh": "data plugh",
  "xyzzy": "data xyzzy",
  "thud": "data thud"
}
```

How can I fill the input box with the data using the key

```js
let data = {
  "foobar": "data foobar",
  "foo": "data foo",
  "bar": "data bar",
  "baz": "data baz",
  "qux": "data qux",
  "quux": "data quux",
  "corge": "data corge",
  "grault": "data grault",
  "garply": "data garply",
  "waldo": "data waldo",
  "fred": "data fred",
  "plugh": "data plugh",
  "xyzzy": "data xyzzy",
  "thud": "data thud"
}
$('input[name=foobar]').val(data['foobar']);
$('input[name=foo]').val(data['foo']);
$('input[name=bar]').val(data['bar']);
...
```

As you can see, the above code gives manual filling. I don't want to use looping, but I want to get value of the related jquery selector string like this:

```js
$('input[name=foobar]').val(data[/=(\w+)\]/.exec(this.selectorstring)[1]]);
```

I expect `this.selectorstring` returns `'input[name=foobar]'`. Is it possible to do this in Javascript / jQuery?

Comment: Any reason you don't just define a function and take the name as parameter?

Comment: I want to fix another person's code with 100+ lines. So it will take more time if it defines a variable.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function `.val(function() { return data[$(this).attr("name")]; })`

Comment: It will take more time to write ``myFunction = name =>$(`input[name=${name}]`).val(data[name])`` than to copy/paste the same code 100 times?

Comment: There's no way to determine the "selector" as it's not a thing once the jquery collection has been generated.  eg `$(this)` doesn't have a string selector.  What would the selector be with `$(this).nextAll().addBack()`?

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, It does. Because the codes contain many different selector names.

Comment: Maybe something like: `Object.keys(data).each((i, e) => $("input[name='" + e + '"]").val(data[e])`  (not checked for accuracy, concept applies)

Comment: @Jordy which wasn't at all clear from the question that only shows the same selector...

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks but I don't want to use looping now.

Comment: I just want get related selector string

Comment: var s = "input[name=bar]"; $(s).val(data[/=(\w+)\]/.exec(s)[1]]);`  seems a bit strange if you know the selector to then use a regex + exec.   Perhaps you could provide some other examples of *"many different selector names"* where this approach would actually benefit rather than a much simpler approach.

Comment: @freedomn-m [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv32W.png) can be the example.

Comment: If you use a version of jquery before 1.7 then you can use `.selector`.  See https://api.jquery.com/selector/

Comment: *"looking for an up-to-date answer*" - the *answer* is a simple: **No, it's not possible.**  There are plenty of work-arounds/solutions, but you seem to want to dismiss them out of hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not want to use loops and prefer manual copy-pasting, you can do this:

```js
(s => s.val(data[/=(\w+)\]/.exec(s.selector)[1]]))($('input[name=foobar]'));
```

Or, as @freedomn-m suggested, use a variable instead:

```js
var s = "input[name=foobar]"; $(s).val(data[/=(\w+)]/.exec(s)[1]]);
```

You cannot directly put the selector into `this.selectorstring` without function context.

```js
let data = {
    "foobar": "data foobar",
    "foo": "data foo",
    "bar": "data bar",
    "baz": "data baz",
    "qux": "data qux",
    "quux": "data quux",
    "corge": "data corge",
    "grault": "data grault",
    "garply": "data garply",
    "waldo": "data waldo",
    "fred": "data fred",
    "plugh": "data plugh",
    "xyzzy": "data xyzzy",
    "thud": "data thud"
  };
  
  (s => s.val(data[/=(\w+)\]/.exec(s.selector)[1]]))($('input[name=foobar]'));
  (s => s.val(data[/=(\w+)\]/.exec(s.selector)[1]]))($('input[name=foo]'));
  (s => s.val(data[/=(\w+)\]/.exec(s.selector)[1]]))($('input[name=bar]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<input name="foobar" />
<input name="foo" />
<input name="bar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option which like the others is also quick and easy to copy and paste for a lot of lines. It is a simple function where you reference it just like $(selector).val but instead reference the function name and pass the data object (or not but I prefer to pass it).

```js
let data = {
  "foobar": "data foobar",
  "foo": "data foo",
  "bar": "data bar",
  "baz": "data baz",
  "qux": "data qux",
  "quux": "data quux",
  "corge": "data corge",
  "grault": "data grault",
  "garply": "data garply",
  "waldo": "data waldo",
  "fred": "data fred",
  "plugh": "data plugh",
  "xyzzy": "data xyzzy",
  "thud": "data thud"
}

$.fn.setVal = function(data){
  $(this).val(data[$(this).prop("name")])
}

$('input[name=foobar]').setVal(data);
$('input[name=bar]').setVal(data);
$('input[name=foo]').setVal(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="foobar">
<input type="text" name="foo">
<input type="text" name="bar">
```

Comment: Ideally you should use `$.fn.extend` to create your own function and allow chaining. Your current function breaks when you, for example, do `$('input[name=foobar]').setVal(data).css("color", "red")` or even `$('input').setVal(data)`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `name` property dynamically is as simple as:

```
$('input[name=foobar]').val(function() {
    return data[this.name];
});
```

But then, I don't understand why you want to copy-paste a line *n* times instead of looping, for example:

```js
const data = {
  "foobar": "data foobar",
  "foo": "data foo",
  "bar": "data bar",
  "baz": "data baz",
  "qux": "data qux",
  "quux": "data quux",
  "corge": "data corge",
  "grault": "data grault",
  "garply": "data garply",
  "waldo": "data waldo",
  "fred": "data fred",
  "plugh": "data plugh",
  "xyzzy": "data xyzzy",
  "thud": "data thud"
};
$(function() {
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    $(`input[name="${key}"]`).val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="foobar"><br>
  <input type="text" name="foo"><br>
  <input type="text" name="bar"><br>
</form>
```

Or loop the other way round:

```js
const data = {
  "foobar": "data foobar",
  "foo": "data foo",
  "bar": "data bar",
  "baz": "data baz",
  "qux": "data qux",
  "quux": "data quux",
  "corge": "data corge",
  "grault": "data grault",
  "garply": "data garply",
  "waldo": "data waldo",
  "fred": "data fred",
  "plugh": "data plugh",
  "xyzzy": "data xyzzy",
  "thud": "data thud"
};
$(function() {
  $("input[name]").each(function() {
    $(this).val(data[this.name] || `no value for ${this.name}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="foobar"><br>
  <input type="text" name="foo"><br>
  <input type="text" name="bar"><br>
  <input type="text" name="asdf"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Old School JavaScript

There are a few JavaScript interfaces that are specialized for the `<form>` and form controls. For details review the comments in the example and the links below.

- [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements)
- [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [Form Controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content)

### Example

```js
/**
 * (dataStr) Define a properly formatted JSON as a String by wrapping
 * it with backticks "`" located under the "esc" key on a QWERTY
 * keyboard.
 */
const dataStr = `{
  "Alpha": "system engine",
  "Beta": "task-force",
  "Delta": "function",
  "Gamma": "Optimized",
  "Epsilon": "neutral",
  "Zeta": "Distributed",
  "NILL": "Not Applicable",
  "NA": 0,
  "Psi": "IV",
  "Omega": "I, II, III, IV"
}`;
// (dataObj) Parse JSON into an Object literal
const dataObj = JSON.parse(dataStr);
// (F) Reference <form> by #id or [name]
const F = document.forms.main;
/**
 * (fc) Collect all form controls ("FC") into an array-like object known
 * as a HTMLFormControlsCollection ("HFCC").
 * In this case all <input>, <select>, and <fieldset> can
 * be referenced by it's #id, [name], or index.
 *
 * ex. 
 *   #id: <input id="A">
 *   Dot notation:     fc.A
 *   OR
 *   Bracket notation: fc["A"]
 *
 * ex. 
 *   [name]: <input name="B">
 *   Dot notation:     fc.B
 *   OR 
 *   Bracket notation: fc["B"]
 *
 * ex. 
 *   index of 3rd "FC": <input id="A"> <input name="B"> <select>
 *   Bracket notation: fc[2]
 *
 * NOTE: If there's more than one "FC" with the same [name]
 * they will automatically become a new "HFFC".
 */
const fc = F.elements;
/**
 * (dataArr) Convert dataObj into an Array of key/value pairs
 *
 * ex. 
 *   from:       {key: val,...}
 *     dataObj = {"A": "system engine",... }
 *
 *   to:         [[key, val],...]
 *     dataArr = [["A", "system engine"],... ]
 */
const dataArr = Object.entries(dataObj);
/**
 * Iterate through the array of key/value pairs.
 * Pass each array element as a destructured sub-array.
 *
 * ex. 
 *   key/value pair:      [key, val]
 *     dataArray.forEach(([key, val]) => ...)
 *
 * If a "FC" exists with a [name] that matches the current key...
 * reference fc by using bracket notation and current key
 * to reference the specific "FC" by it's [name].
 *
 * ex.
 *   on first iteration: <input name="A">
 *     fc[key] ~ fc["A"]
 *
 * Then assign val to fc["A"] with the .value property.
 *
 * ex.
 *   on first iteration: <input name="A" value="system engine">
 *     fc[key].value = val ~ fc["A"].value = "system engine"
 */
dataArr.forEach(([key, val]) => {
  if (fc[key]) {
    /**
     * See |SELECT A or B| comment in HTML section.
     * If "B.", then uncomment the proceeding area.
     * (Remove/Add "/" between "/" and "/")
     *//*
        if (fc[key].matches("select")) {
          const values = val.split(", ");
          values.forEach(v => fc[key].add(new Option(v, v)));
        } else //*/
    fc[key].value = val;
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: ". . ";
}

label,
input,
select {
  width: 40vw;
  margin: 4px;
  font: inherit;
}

code {
  font-family: Consolas;
  color: #930;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <fieldset class="grid">
    <legend>Assign Values to Keys</legend>
    <input name="Alpha">
    <input name="Beta">
    <input name="Gamma">
    <input name="Delta">
    <input name="Epsilon">
    <input name="Zeta">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="grid">
    <legend><code>SELECT</code>s have Multiple Values</legend>
    <!-- |SELECT A or B|
      Two possibilities may exist concerning <select>s 
        A. <option>s within <select> preexist in HTML layout.
        B. <select>s have no <option>s
      Uncomment/comment the applicable areas.
    -->
    <!-- A. (Add/Remove ">" after "--") -->
    <label>
      All <code>OPTION</code>s preexist<br>
      <select name="Psi">
        <option value="I">I</option>
        <option value="I">II</option>
        <option value="I">III</option>
        <option value="IV">IV</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <!-- A. -->
    <!-- B. (Add/Remove ">" after "--") --
    <label>
      <code>OPTION</code>s <b>DO NOT</b> exist<br>
      <select name="Omega"></select>
    </label>
    <!-- B. -->
  </fieldset>
</form>
```